# Android ListView tries to reuse visible cell after setImageBitmap call with async downloaded bitmap

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, convertview, getview

I have very strange behavior when ListView adapter provides into getView method the same convertViews even if all of them are visible:
  
    `getView(); 0; holder: ViewHolder@4289bde8
    getView(); 1; holder: ViewHolder@4289bde8
    getView(); 4; holder: ViewHolder@4289bde8
    getView(); 2; holder: ViewHolder@4289bde8
    getView(); 3; holder: ViewHolder@4289bde8`

It occurs only if I call setImageBitmap with async downloaded image. If this method is called with Bitmap that is static (e.g. Bitmap from Resources) - everything works as designed:

    `getView(); 2; holder: ViewHolder@426fd408
    getView(); 1; holder: ViewHolder@42899128
    getView(); 0; holder: ViewHolder@4289bdf0
    getView(); 4; holder: ViewHolder@4289b598
    getView(); 5; holder: ViewHolder@4289b480`

Answer (score 0):

It became a big surprise for me, but the issue was related with my misprint, when I accidentally specified `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the ListView.
Right after I changed it to a correct `android:layout_height="match_parent"` value, recycling mechanism started to work correctly even for async bitmaps!